# Can we connect to a Wi-Fi automatically?

Tags: applications, wi-fi

Suppose I have wifi password for a particular connection,so can I connect to it automatically?

Let's say I save the password on my server(Let's just say I have access to that),so can we connect to it automatically without doing anything? (For the first time user also)

Sample scenario: I have an app, and when I come in the range of the wifi, i automatically get connected to it.

Thanks.

Comment: Can't we do that? First time you've got to connect manually. Once the connection is stored, your device will always connect to that WiFi automatically whenever it's in reach.

Comment: I mean what if we don't enter it manually, can we do it otherwise? With some code? I want a functionality through which the user automatically get connected without doing anything. (we will know the password).

Comment: I think it is not possible if not very hard and complicated without root

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wefi.wefi, like this app. This doesn't require the device to be rooted. Right?

Comment: No. But neither does it add passwords (for the WiFi AP) to your device. I've also never heard it connects you automatically. If that were possible, it would be the first thing I'd disable – for security reasons. You never know where that would get you in.